# 1-click switch user shortkey

Tags: shortcuts, autohotkey, fast-user-switching

So I'm looking for the most efficient method of switching between one user to another, on Windows 10.

What I'm hoping to find is a command wherein I could add username and password (disregarding the huge security issue of that, as it's on home computer).

Any ideas?

**Background:**

So far I've only been able to use tsdiscon on a shortcut to swiftly disconnect a user, but I'll still need to click on the user I wish to log in with, and go through the login procedure.

Alternatively I'm looking at autohotkey maybe, but it has limited use once disconnected, and I'm already beyound that with the tsdiscon command.

**EDIT**

Ok I'm been made aware of tscon command, which apparently would do excatly what I'm looking for - however I can't seem to figure out how to use it.

Anyone can help with with code example for tscon command?

Example I have a user named User2 with Password 123456 - what would the tscon command look like?

tscon command uses the following syntax:
tscon SessionID | SessionName [ /server:ServerName] [/dest:SessionName] [/password:Password] /v

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321703

Comment: `tscon` is for connecting to servers not switching users on a desktop.

Comment: Yes ok - I guess that could explain why I couldn't make it work. However tsdiscon is also purposed for servers, but still provides good functionality thus far on quickly disconnecting a user.

Comment: Are you trying to do something that can be accomplished by running a task or process as a different user?  Or are you just wanting to efficiently switch users, desktops, etc. on a home machine by easily clicking an icon?

Comment: @JJohnston2 I'm solely looking for the most efficiently user switch possible, something that could be boiled down to just a 1-click icon. Thanks for the other suggestion tho, but that's not what i'm looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

After searching on google and experimenting for months, I did it!!! Very proud of me :-) Me and my wife share 1 laptop (saves space/money) we trust each other 110% and had to switch with 3 or 4 clicks a trillion times a day. We have no passwords. Somehow in the past I allready got rid of the lockscreen (google, 10-forums will probably explain). Netplwiz for no psswrds required, as I can remember I made changes to the registry to allow windows 10 home for 0 psswrds (have to google if necessary). Not sure if any of the above is required for this to work. What is required:

1. Make both users admin, if else this won't work.
2. See if tscon.exe is in your windows/system32 folder. If it isn't: download it somewhere and put it there. (there's multiple versions, find the right one by testing in admin cmd-prompt by seeing if it recognises "tscon" as a command). W10 Home doesn't have it standard, but does work with it.
3. Copy below text into a textfile and save as User1.vbs file to a conveniant location (I made a dedicated folder C:\Switchuser)

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Shell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c tscon 1 /dest:console", , "runas", 0

WScript.Quit

4. Do this again for User2.vbs, but change the part "/c tscon 1 /dest:console" in "/c tscon 2 /dest:console"
5. Rightclick the (apropriate) vbs-file and make a shortcut to desktop.
6. Rightclick the shortcut and change the icon to something you want (I found a nice icon in C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll)

you now have a double-click solution to the fastest userswitching ever, but making it a one-click solution:

7. Rightclick your shortcut and do with it what this guy did (if you don't, on the taskbar your shortcut wil always get the fugly wscript-icon): [In Windows 7 I cannot change icon of VBS file from wscript icon And put multiple ones on the taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/665350/in-windows-7-i-cannot-change-icon-of-vbs-file-from-wscript-icon-and-put-multiple)
8. drag your shortcut to the taskbar (on both users)
9. Bob's your uncle

Donations and cheersmessages welcome :-D